# Algorithm converting lotto ticket number to integer value and back again

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I'm looking for the algorithm to convert a lotto ticket number to an integer value an back again.

Let's say the lotto number can be between 1 and 45 and a tickets contains 6 unique numbers. This means there are a maximum of 8145060 unique lotto tickets.

eg:

```
01-02-03-04-05-06 = 1
01-02-03-04-05-07 = 2
        .
        .
        .
39-41-42-43-44-45 = 8145059
40-41-42-43-44-45 = 8145060
```

I'd like to have a function (C# preferable but any language will do) which converts between a lotto ticket and an integer and back again. At the moment I use the quick and dirty method of pre-calculating everything, which needs a lot of memory.

Comment: Does it have to be this specific integer, or will any unique integer do? Why do you need to do this? Possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: you could try using `.GetHashCode()` but there are chances of collisions

Comment: @DanielA.White also you cannot map from hash codes back to the original strings.

Comment: It needs to be this specific integer, a hash won't do. I need to be able to group a range of lotto tickets together based on the integer number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For enumerating integer combinations, you need to use the [combinatorial number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system). Here's a basic implementation in C#:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class CombinatorialNumberSystem
{
    // Helper functions for calculating values of (n choose k).
    // These are not optimally coded!
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected static BigInteger factorial(int n) {
        BigInteger f = 1;
        while (n > 1) f *= n--;
        return f;
    }
    
    protected static int binomial(int n, int k) {
        if (k > n) return 0;
        return (int)(factorial(n) / (factorial(k) * factorial(n-k)));
    }
    
    // In the combinatorial number system, a combination {c_1, c_2, ..., c_k}
    // corresponds to the integer value obtained by adding (c_1 choose 1) +
    // (c_2 choose 2) + ... + (c_k choose k)
    // NOTE: combination values are assumed to start from zero, so
    // a combination like {1, 2, 3, 4, 5} will give a non-zero result
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static int combination_2_index(int[] combo) {
        int ix = 0, i = 1;
        Array.Sort(combo);
        foreach (int c in combo) {
            if (c > 0) ix += binomial(c, i);
            i++;
        }
        return ix;
    }
    
    // The reverse of this process is a bit fiddly. See Wikipedia for an
    // explanation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_number_system
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static int[] index_2_combination(int ix, int k) {
        List<int> combo_list = new List<int>();
        while (k >= 1) {
            int n = k - 1;
            if (ix == 0) {
                combo_list.Add(n);
                k--;
                continue;
            }
            int b = 0;
            while (true) {
                // (Using a linear search here, but a binary search with
                // precomputed binomial values would be faster)
                int b0 = b;
                b = binomial(n, k);
                if (b > ix || ix == 0) {
                    ix -= b0;
                    combo_list.Add(n-1);
                    break;
                }
                n++;
            }
            k--;
        }
        int[] combo = combo_list.ToArray();
        Array.Sort(combo);
        return combo;
    }
}
```

The calculations are simpler if you work with combinations of integers that start from zero, so for example:

```
00-01-02-03-04-05 = 0
00-01-02-03-04-06 = 1
        .
        .
        .
38-40-41-42-43-44 = 8145058
39-40-41-42-43-44 = 8145059
```

[You can play around with this code at ideone if you like.](https://ideone.com/lxWvhu)

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. It does precisely what I want it to do.  
I've never heard of "combinatorial number system" so time for me to go read up on it on wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

there seem to be actually 45^6 distinct numbers, a simple way is to treat the ticket number as a base-45 number and convert it to base 10:

```
 static ulong toDec(string input){
     ulong output = 0;
     var lst = input.Split('-').ToList();
     for (int ix =0; ix< lst.Count; ix++)
     {
        output = output + ( (ulong.Parse(lst[ix])-1) *(ulong) Math.Pow(45 , 5-ix));
     }
     return output;
 }
```

examples:

- 01-01-01-01-01-01 => 0
- 01-01-01-01-01-02 => 1
- 01-01-01-01-02-01 => 45
- 45-45-45-45-45-45 => 8303765624

Comment: Very nice idea, unfortunately for a lotto ticket number an individual number can only exists once. So 01-01-... is not a valid lotto number. Because of that I can't have it in the integer range.  

The total number of lotto tickets numbers ca be calculated using this formula:  

n! / r!(n-r)!  

where   

    n - total number of possible numbers (eg 45)  
    r - number of numbers chosen (eg 6)  
    ! - factorial